# Need to Uncheck radio with condition using angular JD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to uncheck the radio button in specific condition.

```
<input type="radio" name="XXX" value="add" data-ng-model="XXX"/>Add
```

In this radio i want to uncheck when the condition attain like

```
<input type="radio" name="XXX" value="add" data-ng-model="XXX" ng-unchecked="add.new='false'"/>Add
```

Is there any way i can do this in simple method

Comment: ```ngIf``` my be what you are looking for --- there is an example halfway down this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald -- My priority is unchecking..The radio is already checked by some condition. When other condition add.new is attained that radio should uncheck.

Answer (score 1):

As you bind the input to your model, whenever you uncheck the box, the model will be unset too and vice versa anyway.

So if model and form are in sync anyway, the best place to realize this would be clearly to unset the value in the controller:

```
if($scope.add.new) {
  $scope.XXX = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple using the ng-checked directive

```
<input type="radio" name="XXX" value="add" data-ng-model="XXX" ng-checked="add.new"/>Add
```

If add.new resolves to a truthy value the button will be checked, if not, it will not be checked.

Comment: My priority is unchecking..The radio is already checked by some condition. When other condition add.new is attained that radio should uncheck.

Comment: How is that radio already checked then, could you provide the piece of code that does that?

Comment: The radio is just checked by clicking there is no issue in that. I need to uncheck by some condition. don't get confuse.

Comment: @johnie _uncheck by some condition_, so what condition? You can uncheck it programmatically by setting `add.new` to `false` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="XXX" value="add" data-ng-model="XXX" ng-checked="add.new" ng-click="checkCondition('123')" id="checkbok_123"/>Add

$scope.checkCondition = function(id){
   if(condition is true){
      add.new = true;
   }else{
      add.new = false;
      document.getElementById("checkbox_"+id).checked = false;
   }
}
```